# Trying to hide a view based on what button I click using prepareforsegue

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiview

In my FirstViewController I have two buttons called (button1 and button2).

In my SecondViewController I have two views called(visible1 and visible2).

- When I push button1, I will switch to SecondViewController and both
  Views should be visible.
- When I push button2, only the View(visible2) should be visible.

I tried this:

```
if (segue.identifier == "segueTest2") {
        let svc = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondViewController

        svc.visible1.hidden = true

}
```

but then i will get an error:
[image]

Comment: its not making any sense. please explain a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

When `prepareForSegue` is called, `destinationViewController.view` is not loaded yet (and outlets are not connected as well). So `visible1` is nil at this point.

IMO best option would be to create some variable `mode` on second view controller that can take values from enum .AllVisible / .OnlySecondVisible. The in prepareForSegue you set `svc.mode = .OnlySecondVisible`. And in SecondViewController.viewDidLoad you configure your UI according to selected `mode`. So first view controller not editing second view controller UI directly. Weak coupling is good.

Another (easier) workaround is to write:

```
if (segue.identifier == "segueTest2") {
    let svc = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondViewControlle
    let _ = svc.view  // trigger viewDidLoad
    svc.visible1.hidden = true
}
```

But it's poor code design...

Comment: Thank you  Glyuck! How should the 'mode' Look like? I am an  Beginner. Thanks dir your help.